# Parameter was not found during prepare using Prepared Statement in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, crud

I am using Prepared Statement in C# with MySQL and this error is occurring, what I am missing?

```
cmd.Connection = conexao;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM contato WHERE name LIKE @q OR email LIKE @q";
cmd.Prepare();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@q", $"%{txtBuscar.Text}%");
```

Comment: Swap the last line with the previous one. Or in other words prepare after adding the parameter to the collection

Comment: You can skip using Prepare

Answer (score 2):

As [posted by Steve in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71897708/parameter-was-not-found-during-prepare-using-prepared-statement-in-c-sharp/71897752#comment127048835_71897708):

> Swap the last line with the previous one. Or in other words prepare after adding the parameter to the collection